# Rails 7 + Devise + Turbo stream not showing errors when sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, turbo-rails

I started new project and am stuck for hours trying to make Sign In page show errors. Though when I try to write incorrect data on Sign up page it returns errors, Sign in completely ignores it.
I found decision concerning devise for rails 7 from [gorails](https://gorails.com/episodes/devise-hotwire-turbo), it didn't help.

Gemfile:

```
gem "devise", git: "https://github.com/ghiculescu/devise.git", branch: "error-code-422"
gem "responders", git: "https://github.com/heartcombo/responders.git"
```

config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
...
config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html, :turbo_stream]
...
```

Did it in order not to add new controller and custom error as it was shown in video. Also, console returns 422, but in terminal still:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2022-11-29 12:46:57 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"email"=>"test@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "test@example.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 271ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms | Allocations: 1727)


Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"email"=>"test@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.haml
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_error_messages.html.haml (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 12)
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.haml (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 137)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (Duration: 3.5ms | Allocations: 1348)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.haml (Duration: 5.4ms | Allocations: 2506)
Completed 200 OK in 251ms (Views: 6.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 3124)
```

My views are default generated by devise. If I should provide more info, like application.html.haml etc, please tell me.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: Devise 4.9.0 has been released, which fixes this issue. Upgrade Devise and modify your Devise config to match the block below. Configs generated after 4.9.0 will have the correct values.**

From: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/v4.9.0/CHANGELOG.md:

> Devise uses the latest `responders` version (v3.1.0 or higher), which
> allows configuring the status used for validation error responses
> (`error_status`) and for redirects after POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE
> requests (`redirect_status`). For backwards compatibility, Devise
> keeps `error_status` as `:ok` which returns a `200 OK` response, and
> `redirect_status` to `:found` which returns a `302 Found` response,
> but you can configure it to return `422 Unprocessable Entity` and `303 See Other` respectively, to match the behavior expected by
> Hotwire/Turbo:

```rb
# config/initializers/devise.rb
Devise.setup do |config|
  # ...
  config.responder.error_status = :unprocessable_entity
  config.responder.redirect_status = :see_other
  # ...
end
```

---

**Original answer / workaround (no longer needed):**

This is a known issue with Devise, and for now the recommended fix is to disable Turbo on Devise's log in/out forms.

From https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/Troubleshooting-Rails-7-and-Turbo-Drive :

> Since Turbolinks is replaced with Turbo Drive (That is part of Hotwire), we need to ensure full-page redirects when submitting devise forms.

One trick you can use for Devise's log out link, since it uses the HTTP DELETE method, is to change it to a button, like so:

```
<%= button_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, data: { turbo: false } %>
```

... but the wiki link above has other samples as well.

There are some more details and discussions here:

- https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5358
- https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/issues/388